# Scaling method fails to satisfy JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I’m trying to make a position, length and circle classes based on given JUnit in order to eventually output them graphically. But I’m stuck in one of the methods for days now.
I tried to truncate precisions but then my equals method failed.

JUnit for Scale:

```
public void testScale(){
    Length inch2 = Length.unit.scale(320.0);
    assertTrue(inch2 != null);
    assertEquals(Length.inch,inch2);
    assertFalse(inch2.equals(Length.unit)); 
    Length unit2 = Length.cm.scale(1.0/125.98425197);
    assertTrue(unit2 != null);
    assertEquals(Length.unit,unit2); // This is the line my scale method fails
                                     // Here my unit2 has a length of 1.0001249999881234
                                     // and my constant cm has a length of 1.0 but 
                                     // truncating those precisions caused my equals                                   
                                     // method to fails.  
    assertFalse(unit2.equals(Length.cm));
    Length z = Length.meter.scale(0);
    assertTrue(z != null);
    assertEquals(Length.zero,z);
    assertFalse(z.equals(Length.meter));
    assertFalse(Length.zero.equals(null));
}
```

My scale method:

```
public Length scale(double d) {
    if (d < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    else {
        return new Length(d* this.length);
    }
}
```

**I suspect maybe the problem is coming from my equals method but in the given JUnit it is passing the tests.**

JUnit for Equals:

```
public void testEquals(){
    assertFalse(Length.unit.equals("Not a length"));
    assertFalse(Length.inch.equals(null));
    assertEquals(Length.zero,Length.unit.scale(0.0000001));
    assertTrue(Length.unit.scale(0.0000001).compareTo(Length.zero) == 0);
    assertTrue(Length.zero.compareTo(Length.unit.scale(0.0000001)) == 0);
    assertFalse(Length.unit.scale(0.0000015).equals(Length.zero));
    assertTrue(Length.unit.scale(0.0000015).compareTo(Length.zero) > 0);
    assertTrue(Length.zero.compareTo(Length.unit.scale(0.0000015)) < 0);
}
```

My Equals Method:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == null || !(other instanceof Length)) {
        return false;
    }
    Length o = (Length) other;
    if (Math.abs(this.length - o.length) < 0.000001) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please help

---

Link for all my code:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bz400f8y0ufx381/59aUTilrBt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are testing too many things at once.**

A unit test should be one unit of code - one aspect of the code as opposed to everything at once.

I also notice that you don't have any of your test methods annotated with `@Test`; you should be doing this with JUnit4 tests.

So, for your first test, you have a relatively small `scale` method you want to exercise.  Let's enumerate the cases:

- `d < 0`.  I should expect an `IllegalArgumentException`.
- `d >= 0`.  I should expect a new instance of `Length` with a size some multiple of `d` and whatever the set length of the instance is.

What this looks like is **two** discrete tests:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void scaleShouldThrowExceptionWhenInvalidLength() {

}

@Test
public void scaleShouldBehaveNormally() {

}
```

I leave you to fill in the blanks, since I don't know what object `scale` is attached to.

Equals is the same way - you want to exercise each condition of the equivalence.

<sup>By the way, you can do `return Math.abs(this.length - o.length) < 0.000001` for your conditions.  `return true` and `return false` scream bad practice.</sup>

- The object you're passing in is `null`.
- The object you're passing in is not an instance of `Length`.
- The object you're passing in fails `Math.abs(this.length - o.length) < 0.000001`.
- The object you're passing in passes `Math.abs(this.length - o.length) < 0.000001`.

So the above are four discrete tests.

```
@Test
public void equalsShouldFailIfNull() {

}

@Test
public void equalsShouldFailIfNotInstanceOfLength() {

}

@Test
public void equalsDoesNotMeetCondition() {

}

@Test
public void equalsMeetsCondition() {

}
```

Filling in the blanks, I leave as an exercise to the reader.

Be **very careful** when dealing with floating-point numbers.  You won't always get an exact representation back (that is, you may get an imprecise value when dealing with fractions).  Be certain that your equals method is well-defined to respect what could happen when you don't have an exact decimal value to work with.

Alternatively, if you really need the decimal precision, use a `BigDecimal` instead.